# VBA Excel Copying Cell contents to another via column and row offset

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code

```
Sub A_Copy_To_Prior_Row_column()
'
' A_Copy_To_Prior_Row_column Macro
'

'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("R183").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Where R183 is I need to not a specific cell, but a cell based on minus 1 row, and +17 columns of the selected/highlighted cell I wish to copy

Answer (score 0):

```
activecell.Offset(-1, 17).Value = activecell.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub A_Copy_To_Prior_Row_column()
'
' A_Copy_To_Prior_Row_column Macro
'

'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection
        .Copy
         ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=.Offset(-1, 17)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @DennisMoore, did you get through it?